# Principal square root of Pauli Y gate in Qiskit?

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, programming, gate-synthesis, pauli-gates

I've seen a similar question asked ([How do I compute the square root of the $Y$ gate?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11677/how-do-i-compute-the-square-root-of-the-y-gate)) but I'm trying to understand how I can use the gates $Y^{\frac{1}{2}}$ or $Y^{\frac{1}{4}}$ in Qiskit in terms of other building blocks, if it is possible.

Is there a way to use the gate $Y^{\frac{1}{2}} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}
 + \frac{1}{2}i & -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}i\\
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}i & \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}i
\end{bmatrix}$ in Qiskit? I can say that $Y = iRY(\pi)$ and compute the square root manually, but how can I describe such an operation, if possible, in Qiskit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason this took a while to find, but has a simple solution:

```
circ.append(YGate().power(1/2), [qbit])
```

Where `circ` is the `QuantumCircuit` object and `qbit` is the register to apply the gate on.